# How to run two real time processes simultaneously in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, real-time

I recently tried to send some sensor data (which is time changing) from my smartphone to PC and then from my PC to the arduino, since I don't have a bluetooth or wifi module for my arduino. I used an app to stream sensor data to PC and used the below python code to transfer it to arduino. But everytime I execute the script only reading the data stream is performed but it is never writing the data to the arduino. If I stop running the script(ctrl+Z) then the last values are updated into the arduino. I need help in doing the two things simultaneously.

```
import socket, traceback
import serial
import time

host='192.168.100.8'
port=4000
ser=serial.Serial(port='COM3',baudrate=115200)
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
s.bind((host, port))
k=[]
while 1:
        try:
                message, address = s.recvfrom(8192)
                k=map(str,message.strip().split(','))
                yaw,pitch,roll=k[-3:]
                #print yaw,pitch,roll
                l=yaw+','+pitch+','+roll+'\0'
                print l
                ser.write(l)
        except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
                exit()
        except:
                traceback.print_exc()
```

Comment: I see you have written some print statements. If you have both print statements not commented out, but comment out the `ser.write(l)`, does it print two lines on the PC everytime the smartphone sends a message?

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that the reason it does not write until you close your script is that you never flush your output. When you close your script your output is automatically flushed, which is why that is the only time you see it working currently.

```
ser.write(l)
ser.flush()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer evan, but even though after using flush() my output has no change. I am still not able to write to arduino.